# Merge Row Group Values in SSRs

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is there any ways to merge row group values.suppose Department rowgroup display 3 values Accounts,IT and Finance,both Finance and Account has the same constant values falls within.My problems when run the reports both a divided into different row cells but have same values.want both to combine into 1 row, so matrix table can have only 2 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of grouping on Department, i.e.

`=Fields!Department.Value`,

group on a expression that will return the same value for Finance and Account, e.g.

`=IIf(Fields!Department.Value = "Accounts" or Fields!Department.Value = "Finance", "Accounts-Finance", Fields!Department.Value)`.

In the above example this will give two groups, **Accounts-Finance** and **IT**, instead of the three original groups.

Similarly, you could add this expression as a calculated field to the Dataset being used, then group on the calculated field. This is the same approach but will move the logic out of the matrix so it can be used elsewhere in the report.